How to show the screen of a physical device inside VS Code when using Flutter?

I need to use the Screen Mirroring feature, its the same feature that
is being present in the Android Studio. Here we can connect our
physical device using Wi-Fi or Cable & by enabling the Device
Mirroring Options, we can actually see the screen of our connected
physical device and control it using our laptop. I need to be able to
use this same feature in VS Code, since I've switched back to VS Code
for coding, due to the limitations that my laptop is having, and
Android Studio uses a lot of memory & CPU, so I needed a light weight
IDE for development. So I am just curious to know that is there any
option/way/method/extension which can produce the same?


you can use a program called MirrorGo

I suggest to use Vysor
